# Convert a nested object with n levels into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested object, something similar to this:

```
var obj = {
    "prop1": {
       "prop1A": "A",
       "prop1B": {
                  "prop1BA": "BA"
       }, 
       "prop1C": "C"
    }  
};
```

My final goal is to filter this object to specific pre defined keys, according to another schema object, for example:

```
var filterSchema = {
    "prop1":["prop1A", {"prop1B":["prop1BA"]}]
};
```

(The filter keys are predefined, I can structure this object differently if you have a better idea...

The output should be an array. In our case:

```
["A","BA"]
```

I managed to do this using recursion over the object. I was wondering if there is more elegant way for achieving this (tried using jQuery's map/extend with no luck)

**EDIT**
I know that this is a "N" level problem which should be solved by recursion. The difference here is that I have the pre-defined filter which already have the "N" levels. So I though maybe I can filter the Objet using the filter Array and than convert it into an array.

**EDIT2**
Thanks you all for the different answers. This is my own solution for the problem (which I was looking for a more elegant one in the beginning):
[My solution](http://jsbin.com/fimegajale/3/edit?js,console)

```
            var obj = {
        "prop1": {
           "prop1A": "A",
           //"prop1B": {
           //           "prop1BA": "BA"
           //}, 
           "prop1C": "C",
           "prop1D": "D",
           "prop1E": {"prop1E1": "444"}
        },
        "prop2": "12345"
    };


    var schemaObj = {
        "prop1": {
           "prop1A": "true",
           "prop1B": {
                      "prop1BA": "true"
           }, 
           "prop1C": "true"
        },
        "prop2": "true"
    };

var resultsArray = [];
var keys = Object.keys(schemaObj);
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
  if(obj[keys[i]]){
      parser(schemaObj[keys[i]], obj[keys[i]]);    
  }
}


function parser(v,o){
  if( typeof v === "string" ){
      resultsArray.push(o);    
  }
  else{
    var keys2 = Object.keys(v);  
    for(var j=0;j<keys2.length;j++){
      if(o[keys2[j]]){
        parser(v[keys2[j]], o[keys2[j]]);
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(resultsArray);
```

Just a reminder about the question - **I already had the recursion solution**. I am looking for a different solution

Comment: Removed all references to JSON.

Comment: Curious, how is recursion in any way inelegant here? Seems (perf-scaling issues aside) to be an ideal use case...

Comment: Here is no way else but recursion

Comment: More elegant than what? You've not shown us your solution.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if we included the "prop1B" key? `["A", {"prop1BA": "BA"}, "C"]`?

Comment: @squint - the solution uses regular recursion in order to iterate over the "N" levels. It was too hard for me to convert my complex solution into this simple example. I'll try to...

Comment: I believe your example's desired output should be `["A","BA"]`, no? Apart from that neither of your samples is syntactically valid. I get a feeling that you don't have an exact, dependable spec of what you want yourself, yet.

Comment: @Tomalak - thanks for the correction. Why isn't the samples valid? I wanted to simplify by adding simple samples instead of adding my own complicated code.

Comment: Try them - both contain an error.

Comment: @Tomalak - thanks for your comment. I updated the samples to be valid

Comment: I take it there can't be more than one key per object in you filter schema?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has `eval` that allows you to create new code at runtime. A possible solution is to using recursion only once to create a string that looks like:

```
code = "[obj.prop1.prop1A, obj.prop1.prop1B.prop1BA]"
```

then you can create a data conversion function with

```
f = eval("function(obj){return " + code + "]}")
```

and use it with `f(x)` to get your array.

This is also the most efficient solution if you have to extract the data many times.

For example:

```
function mkFilter(schema) {
    var parts = [];
    function xtract(s, prefix) {
        if (typeof s === "string") {
            parts.push(prefix + s);
        } else if (s && s.constructor === Array) {
            s.forEach(function(x){ xtract(x, prefix); });
        } else {
            for (var f in s) {
                xtract(s[f], prefix + f + ".");
            }
        }
    }
    xtract(schema, "obj.");
    var code = "(function(obj){ return [" + parts.join(", ") + "]; })";
    return eval(code);
}
```

passing `schemaFilter` as argument `mkFilter` will return a function that given an object returns the array; with your input:

```
console.log(mkFilter(filterSchema)(obj));
```

displays `['A', 'BA']`. Of course this approach makes sense if you need to reuse the same filter many times with different objects.

If the object may have missing parts and you don't want the filter to fail but just `undefined` values in the array the code generator needs to be changed slightly:

```
var code = "(function(obj){ return [";
parts.forEach(function(p){
    var chain = p.split(".");
    var expr = "";
    for (var i=0; i<chain.length-1; i++) {
        expr += chain.slice(0, i+1).join(".") + " && ";
    }
    code += expr + p + ",";
});
code += "]; })";
```

This will create in your example a filter evaluating

```
(function(obj){
     return [obj && obj.prop1 && obj.prop1.prop1A,
             obj && obj.prop1 && obj.prop1.prop1B &&
                    obj.prop1.prop1B.prop1BA,];
 })
```

Comment: ...which only works when all the requested properties are there in the source object. (FYI, not my downvote)

Comment: @Tomalak: you can wrap the call in a `try` or generate an expression like `[obj && obj.prop1 && obj.prop1.prop1A, ...]`

Comment: But that would leave potentially a lot of "undefined" values in the resulting array. But it's a creative solution nonetheless.

Comment: @Tomalak: probably some jquery bigot doesn't even understand the term "metaprogramming".

Answer (score 0):

The following function seems to do what you want:

```
function filter(obj, schema, out) {
    var i, schemaItems, schemaItem, isItemLevel;

    if (!obj || !schema) return;

    out = out || {values: []};
    isItemLevel = Array.isArray(schema);
    schemaItems = isItemLevel ? schema : Object.keys(schema);

    for (i = 0; i < schemaItems.length; i++) {
        schemaItem = schemaItems[i];
        if (isItemLevel && typeof schemaItem === "string") {
            out.values.push(obj[schemaItem]);
        } else if (typeof schemaItem === "object") {
            filter(obj, schemaItem, out);
        } else if (typeof schemaItem === "string") {
            filter(obj[schemaItem], schema[schemaItem], out);
        }
    }

    return out.values;
}
```

called as

```
var obj = {
    "prop1": {
       "prop1A": "A",
       "prop1B": {
           "prop1BA": "BA"
       }, 
       "prop1C": "C"
    }  
};

var filterSchema = {
    "prop1":["prop1A", {"prop1B":["prop1BA"]}]
};

filter(obj, filterSchema);
```

returns:

```
["A", "BA"]
```

Take it with a grain of salt, it is *by far* not tested well-enough and I certainly don't claim it's the most elegant way of solving this.

It works like this:

- traverse the items of the `schema` (which is either an array or an object)
- for each `schemaItem`

  - if we are in an array and the `schemaItem` is a string, output the respective property value of `obj`
  - else if the `schemaItem` is itself an object, recurse, but stay at the same level in `obj`
  - else if the `schemaItem` is a string, recurse, drilling into both `obj` and `schema`

Comment: Hard to tell without a clear specification, but seems your code assumes the filterSchema always to be an object. Case `obj={x:"A"}` and `filterSchema=["x"]` isn't valid? I'd say the result should be `["A"]`.

Comment: Yes, I guess it would be (having to guess is annoying). I suppose the nested loop could be un-nested to support that scenario. A function that has two points of recursion doesn't feel right anyway.

Comment: Two recursive calls seems to me the cleanest approach, even if nesting arrays is meaningless with this `filterSchema` format.

Comment: @6502 I've unmangled the nested loop. As you've said, still two recursion points necessary, but overall less code & cleaner, plus your proposed situation works.

Comment: This is a nice runtime-based approach. Still I think that just omitting items not found instead of adding `undefined` or raising an error is a bad idea. Calling the function with the schema in the question and getting just `['Y']` without being told which one of the elements was found seems to me useless.

Comment: That's reasonable, and easy enough to fix. Thanks for your time and input. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's map function. you can try the example code snippet in the console, but jquery must be included

```
a = { aa: '123', ab: 'asdasd'}
$.map(a, function(key,val){
    return val;
});
// The map creates an array with the value you return from the code block.
// Output is ["aa", "ab"]
```

for reference see
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: A couple things. Your callback parameters are backwards and I don't think this approaches what the OP needs.

Comment: you are right @squint I didnot know about the map method in array prototype, thanks